# How to access from the web a method of Windows Service?

Tags: wcf, windows-services

i've created simple windows service which gets some xml information once in a hour. I want to have access to this xml information from a website. I know i should create WCF service for that but where do i host the WCF service same application as Windows Service or elsewhere?

If someone knows about blog post or tutorial how to make this work, i would be glad to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your XML information in a database and have your website get it from there.

Comment: Sorry but i can't user Database for that.

Comment: What do you do with your data then, keep it in memory?

Comment: Basically it will be sent to sort of server with it's own database that stores this information in jSon format but for now i would love to keep it in memory which i can access from WCF service.

Comment: So what happens when your Windows service restarts? You lose all your data?

Comment: Yep, problem with with placing of Dictionary declaration... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

you can host wcf services inside a windows service if you want, just manually create a ServiceHost.

Comment: Do you have any more information on how to create ServiceHost?